# Error in syncing of Ropsten testnet on geth node

Tags: synchronization, testnets

I am using a geth node to sync with the ropsten testnet . For the last few days I have been encountering the following error frequently

```
Error: invalid gas used (remote: 7987157 local: 7897475)
```

All the peers get dropped . But in some time , the peers are added back and the sync starts again . What could be causing this and what can be done to resolve this?